# Best ADT representation of AST

Tags: parsing, haskell, compiler-construction, abstract-syntax-tree

I have the following grammar for expressions that I'm trying to represent as a Haskell ADT:

```
Expr = SimpleExpr [OPrelation SimpleExpr]  
SimpleExpr = [OPunary] Term {OPadd Term}  
Term = Factor {OPmult Factor}
```

where:

> {} means 0 or more
>     [] means 0 or 1
>     OPmult, OPadd, OPrelation, OPunary are classes of operators

*Note that this grammar does get precedence right.*

Here's something I tried:

```
data Expr  = Expr SimpleExpr (Maybe OPrelation) (Maybe SimpleExpr)
data SimpleExpr = SimpleExpr (Maybe OPunary) Term [OPadd] [Term]
data Term = Term Factor [OPmult] [Factor]
```

which in hindsight I think is awful, especially the *[OPadd] [Term]* and *[OPmult] [Factor]* parts. Because, for example, in the parse tree for *1+2+3* it would put *[+, +]* in one branch and *[2, 3]* in another, meaning they're decoupled.

What would be a good representation that'll play nice later in the next stages of compilation?

- Decomposing  { } and [ ] into more data types seems like an overkill
- Using lists seems not quite right as it would no longer be a tree (Just a node that's a list)
- *Maybe* for { }. A good idea ?

And finally, I'm assuming after parsing I'll have to pass over the Parse Tree and reduce it to an AST? or should the whole grammar be modified to be less complex? or maybe it's abstract enough?

Comment: `(Maybe OPrelation) (Maybe SimpleExpr)` looks wrong, I'd try `(Maybe (OPrelation, SimpleExpr))`. Similarly for `[(OPadd, Term)]`. Otherwise, you have to be careful to avoid the nothing-just and just-nothing combinations, as well as two lists of distinct length.

Comment: yeah I've thought about tuplin them up, but I'm clearly hand waving at this point and want some guidance

Comment: is it normal to have tuples in the AST?

Comment: Well, they are not too bad, even if often a custom tuple-like data type is better than a plain tuple. If you can find a proper name for `(OPadd, Term)`, define a custom data type, and make a list of that. Using two lists is much worse in my eye, since they would correspond to the grammar `{OPadd} {Term}`, which is completely different.

Comment: yeah that's what I meant be decomposing {} in the question

Comment: You essentially have tuples in your grammar, so naturally they would be in your ADT; what else is `{OPadd Term}` but a list of pairs of an `OPadd` and a `Term`? The most natural and direct representation of that in Haskell is `[ (OPadd, Term) ]`. If you choose something else, do it because you have something specific in mind to gain, not just to avoid tuples.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's an additional answer that might help you.  I don't want to spoil your fun, so here's a very simple example grammar:

```
-- Expr = Term ['+' Term]
-- Term = Factor ['*' Factor]
-- Factor = number | '(' Expr ')'
-- number = one or more digits
```

### Using a CST

As one approach, we can represent this grammar as a concrete syntax tree (CST):

```
data Expr = TermE Term | PlusE Term Term            deriving (Show)
data Term = FactorT Factor | TimesT Factor Factor   deriving (Show)
data Factor = NumberF Int | ParenF Expr             deriving (Show)
```

A Parsec-based parser to turn the concrete syntax into a CST might look like this:

```
expr :: Parser Expr
expr = do
  t1 <- term
  (PlusE t1 <$ symbol "+" <*> term)
    <|> pure (TermE t1)

term :: Parser Term
term = do
  f1 <- factor
  (TimesT f1 <$ symbol "*" <*> factor)
    <|> pure (FactorT f1)

factor :: Parser Factor
factor = NumberF . read <$> lexeme (many1 (satisfy isDigit))
    <|> ParenF <$> between (symbol "(") (symbol ")") expr
```

with helper functions for whitespace processing:

```
lexeme :: Parser a -> Parser a
lexeme p = p <* spaces

symbol :: String -> Parser String
symbol = lexeme . string
```

and main entry point:

```
parseExpr :: String -> Expr
parseExpr pgm = case parse (spaces *> expr) "(string)" pgm of
  Right e -> e
  Left err -> error $ show err
```

after which we can run:

```
> parseExpr "1+1*(3+4)"
PlusE (FactorT (Number 1)) (TimesT (Number 1) (ParenF (PlusE
(FactorT (Number 3)) (FactorT (Number 4)))))
>
```

To convert this into the following AST:

```
data AExpr -- Abstract Expression
  = NumberA Int
  | PlusA AExpr AExpr
  | TimesA AExpr AExpr
```

we could write:

```
aexpr :: Expr -> AExpr
aexpr (TermE t) = aterm t
aexpr (PlusE t1 t2) = PlusA (aterm t1) (aterm t2)

aterm :: Term -> AExpr
aterm (FactorT f) = afactor f
aterm (TimesT f1 f2) = TimesA (afactor f1) (afactor f2)

afactor :: Factor -> AExpr
afactor (NumberF n) = NumberA n
afactor (ParenF e) = aexpr e
```

To interpret the AST, we could use:

```
interp :: AExpr -> Int
interp (NumberA n) = n
interp (PlusA e1 e2) = interp e1 + interp e2
interp (TimesA e1 e2) = interp e1 * interp e2
```

and then write:

```
calc :: String -> Int
calc = interp . aexpr . parseExpr
```

after which we have a crude little calculator:

```
> calc "1 + 2 * (6 + 3)"
19
>
```

### Skipping the CST

As an alternative approach, we could replace the parser with one that parses **directly** into an AST of type `AExpr`:

```
expr :: Parser AExpr
expr = do
  t1 <- term
  (PlusA t1 <$ symbol "+" <*> term)
    <|> pure t1

term :: Parser AExpr
term = do
  f1 <- factor
  (TimesA f1 <$ symbol "*" <*> factor)
    <|> pure f1

factor :: Parser AExpr
factor = NumberA . read <$> lexeme (many1 (satisfy isDigit))
    <|> between (symbol "(") (symbol ")") expr
```

You can see how little the structure of these parsers changes.  All that's disappeared is the distinction between expressions, terms, and factors at the *type* level, and constructors like `TermE`, `FactorT`, and `ParenF` whose only purpose is to allow embedding of these types within each other.

In more complex scenarios, the CST and AST parsers might exhibit bigger differences.  (For example, in a grammar that allowed `1 + 2 + 3`, this might be represented as a single constructor `data Expr = ... | PlusE [Term] | ...` in the CST but with a nested series of binary `PlusA` constructors in the same `AExpr` AST type as above.)

After redefining `parseExpr` to return an `AExpr` and dropping the `aexpr` step from `calc`, everything else stays the same, and we still have:

```
> calc "1 + 2 * (6 + 3)"
19
>
```

### Programs for Reference

Here's the full program using an intermediate CST:

```
-- Calc1.hs, using a CST

{-# OPTIONS_GHC -Wall #-}

module Calc1 where

import Data.Char
import Text.Parsec
import Text.Parsec.String

data Expr = TermE Term | PlusE Term Term            deriving (Show)
data Term = FactorT Factor | TimesT Factor Factor   deriving (Show)
data Factor = NumberF Int | ParenF Expr             deriving (Show)

lexeme :: Parser a -> Parser a
lexeme p = p <* spaces

symbol :: String -> Parser String
symbol = lexeme . string

expr :: Parser Expr
expr = do
  t1 <- term
  (PlusE t1 <$ symbol "+" <*> term)
    <|> pure (TermE t1)

term :: Parser Term
term = do
  f1 <- factor
  (TimesT f1 <$ symbol "*" <*> factor)
    <|> pure (FactorT f1)

factor :: Parser Factor
factor = NumberF . read <$> lexeme (many1 (satisfy isDigit))
    <|> ParenF <$> between (symbol "(") (symbol ")") expr

parseExpr :: String -> Expr
parseExpr pgm = case parse (spaces *> expr) "(string)" pgm of
  Right e -> e
  Left err -> error $ show err

data AExpr -- Abstract Expression
  = NumberA Int
  | PlusA AExpr AExpr
  | TimesA AExpr AExpr

aexpr :: Expr -> AExpr
aexpr (TermE t) = aterm t
aexpr (PlusE t1 t2) = PlusA (aterm t1) (aterm t2)

aterm :: Term -> AExpr
aterm (FactorT f) = afactor f
aterm (TimesT f1 f2) = TimesA (afactor f1) (afactor f2)

afactor :: Factor -> AExpr
afactor (NumberF n) = NumberA n
afactor (ParenF e) = aexpr e

interp :: AExpr -> Int
interp (NumberA n) = n
interp (PlusA e1 e2) = interp e1 + interp e2
interp (TimesA e1 e2) = interp e1 * interp e2

calc :: String -> Int
calc = interp . aexpr . parseExpr
```

and here's the full program for the more traditional solution that skips an explicit CST representation:

```
-- Calc2.hs, with direct parsing to AST

{-# OPTIONS_GHC -Wall #-}

module Calc where

import Data.Char
import Text.Parsec
import Text.Parsec.String

lexeme :: Parser a -> Parser a
lexeme p = p <* spaces

symbol :: String -> Parser String
symbol = lexeme . string

expr :: Parser AExpr
expr = do
  t1 <- term
  (PlusA t1 <$ symbol "+" <*> term)
    <|> pure t1

term :: Parser AExpr
term = do
  f1 <- factor
  (TimesA f1 <$ symbol "*" <*> factor)
    <|> pure f1

factor :: Parser AExpr
factor = NumberA . read <$> lexeme (many1 (satisfy isDigit))
    <|> between (symbol "(") (symbol ")") expr

parseExpr :: String -> AExpr
parseExpr pgm = case parse (spaces *> expr) "(string)" pgm of
  Right e -> e
  Left err -> error $ show err

data AExpr -- Abstract Expression
  = NumberA Int
  | PlusA AExpr AExpr
  | TimesA AExpr AExpr

interp :: AExpr -> Int
interp (NumberA n) = n
interp (PlusA e1 e2) = interp e1 + interp e2
interp (TimesA e1 e2) = interp e1 * interp e2

calc :: String -> Int
calc = interp . parseExpr
```

Comment: omg... If you were just a couple hours earlier! I just did it myself with some struggle.

Answer (score 3):

The AST does not need to be that close to the grammar. The grammar is structured into multiple levels to encode precedence and uses repetition to avoid left-recursion while still being able to correctly handle left-associative operators. The AST does not need to worry about such things.

Instead I'd define the AST like this:

```
data Expr = BinaryOperation BinaryOperator Expr Expr
          | UnaryOperation UnaryOperator Expr
          | Literal LiteralValue
          | Variable Id
data BinaryOperator = Add | Sub | Mul | Div
data UnaryOperator = Not | Negate
```

Comment: Yep it seems I have to ditch the grammar and just do it like this. Thank you

Comment: the AST you provided is recursive so I'll have to introduce more terms (break it up) in my parsing logic to mitigate that, which will effectively parse according to the grammar I was given. Should I keep these two separate, i.e parse using the given grammar and then transform the result to your AST somehow?

Comment: @BanishedBot It is extremely common for ASTs for non-trivial high-level languages to be recursive. I would have assumed your AST and grammar to also be recursive. Specifically I would have expected `Factor` to contain the production `'(' Expr ')'` and consequently the `Factor` data type to contain an alternative that contains an `Expr`. Is that not the case? Without something like that, it'd be impossible to handle arbitrarily nested expressions. And yes, you'd parse your input according to the grammar and then produce the AST while doing so.

Comment: @BanishedBot If you're using a parser generator, the productions in your grammar file would be modelled after your grammar and the actions would produce the AST. If you're using a parser combinator, the structure of your definitions would follow the grammar and the return values would contain the AST nodes. The same goes for a hand-written parser.

Comment: well that last point you mentioned is where I'm kinda stuck at ATM. I'm using parser combinatorics. There seems to be confusion around it based on what I've found online. Some suggest producing a "CST" (which would have it's own data types) and then transforming that to an AST. It's not immediately obvious to me how I'd have my combinatorics parse according to the grammar and return ASt nodes in one swoop. If you could add that to your answer that would help a lot of folks. Thanks!!

Comment: @BanishedBot I'm not sure what you mean by the last point I mentioned. Hand-writing a parser? And what do you mean by there being confusion around it?

Comment: @BanishedBot I'd advise against a CST, but that all depends on how you're actually parsing. I'm not sure how to be more helpful without knowing what your parser currently looks like / what kind of tools you're using or planning to use.

Comment: It's fine thanks. But it's good to know I can do it without a CST (which is great). This should keep me busy for a while

Answer (score 0):

Okay so [Buhr's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51387047/2488240) is quite nice. Here's how I did though (no CST) inspired by sepp2k's response:

The AST:

```
data OP = OPplus | OPminus | OPstar | OPdiv 
    | OPidiv | OPmod |  OPand | OPeq | OPneq 
    | OPless | OPgreater | OPle | OPge 
    | OPin | OPor

data Expr = 
      Relation Expr OP Expr -- > < == >= etc..
    | Unary OP Expr  -- + -
    | Mult Expr OP Expr  -- * / div mod and
    | Add Expr OP Expr  -- + - or
    | FactorInt Int | FactorReal Double 
    | FactorStr String 
    | FactorTrue | FactorFalse 
    | FactorNil 
    | FactorDesig Designator  -- identifiers
    | FactorNot Expr
    | FactorFuncCall FuncCall deriving (Show)
```

The parsers:

```
parseExpr :: Parser Expr
parseExpr = (try $ Relation <$> 
        parseSimpleExpr <*> parseOPrelation <*> parseSimpleExpr)
    <|> parseSimpleExpr

parseSimpleExpr :: Parser Expr
parseSimpleExpr = (try simpleAdd)
    <|> (try $ Unary <$> parseOPunary <*> simpleAdd)
    <|> (try $ Unary <$> parseOPunary <*> parseSimpleExpr)
    <|> parseTerm
    where simpleAdd = Add <$> parseTerm <*> parseOPadd <*> parseSimpleExpr

parseTerm :: Parser Expr
parseTerm = (try $ Mult <$> 
        parseFactor <*> parseOPmult <*> parseTerm)
    <|> parseFactor

parseFactor :: Parser Expr
parseFactor = 
        (parseKWnot >> FactorNot <$> parseFactor)
    <|> (exactTok "true"  >> return FactorTrue)
    <|> (exactTok "false" >> return FactorFalse) 
    <|> (parseNumber)
    <|> (FactorStr <$> parseString)
    <|> (betweenCharTok '(' ')' parseExpr)
    <|> (FactorDesig <$> parseDesignator)
    <|> (FactorFuncCall <$> parseFuncCall)
```

I didn't include basic parsers like parseOPadd as those are what you'd expect and are easy to build.

I still parsed according to the grammar but tweaked it slightly to match my AST.

You could check out the full source which is a compiler for Pascal [here](https://github.com/sam46/Paskell).